# Pragmatically play only audio from YouTube API under iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, youtube, youtube-api

Currently, my application is able to make a search query on YouTube, retrieve the ID for a relevant video, and play the video inside the app.

I know it's a long shot, but is there any way to play simply the audio and ignore the video all together?

I can provide more information and code if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How is it possible to play only an Audio file and not the video file on a ".mp4" file. :)

So as far as i know its not possible.

Regards

Rajeev